# Running powershell logon script on XP

Tags: powershell, authentication

I have the fowling PS script on an users OU.

On win7 put the shortcuts on desktop without problems, but on winXP the policy is applied but no shortcuts on desktop.

I have installed on winXP powershell2, .net 2 SP1, and preferences.
AD is 2012 R2

Can anybody help?
Thanks

```
$links = Import-Csv -Path \\Share$\links.csv

function GetPCOU{
 $SysInfo = New-Object -ComObject "ADSystemInfo"
 $Computer = [ADSI]("LDAP://{0}" -f $SysInfo.GetType().InvokeMember("ComputerName", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, $SysInfo, $null))
 return ([ADSI]$Computer.Parent).OU
} 

for($i=0; $i-le $links.length-1; $i++){

    if ($links[$i].ou -eq (GetPCOU)) {
        $shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
        $desktop = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')

        $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut("$desktop\app1.url")
        $shortcut.TargetPath = $links[$i].xx
        $shortcut.Save()

        $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut("$desktop\app2.url")
        $shortcut.TargetPath = $links[$i].xy
        $shortcut.Save()
    }
}
```

Links file:

```
Ou, app1, app2, appz
OU1, http://xpto.com, http://xxx.xx, http://hhhh.dd
OU2, xxxx, yyyy, zzzz,
```

Comment: On these machines what happens when you run this script manually? What debugging have you done? As you say your script works but we dont have your exact environment.

Comment: Hi, On local winXP machine it works. 
I have put a initial line with a echo to a file like: 
$test = "start"
$test | Out-file  -Path \\Share$\test.txt
This test is negative, Didn’t wrote anything on the text file
My environment is virtual with 2012R2 DC, 1 win XP, 1 win 7, and FS/TS 2003.

Comment: I would have to ask how your GPO is configured. If you run gpresult can you see your GPO targeting your system?

Comment: Hi. I have a logon script. I have run gpresult and the GPO is applied with all outhers.

Comment: no one can help here?